# Is it possible to stream a response from a different server with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, meteor, fetch

First, apologies if the title isn't descriptive enough.

Here is the setup I have to work with :

```
Internet          DMZ         Firewall         LAN
========          ===         ========         ===
                                 :
clients* -------> App -----------:-----------> API
                                 :
```

The `clients` access the `App` through a public URL, this `App` then accesses the internal `API` server and proxy the requests from the client. Clients do *not* have access to the internal `API` server because it's interface cannot be exposed outside of the firewall.

The `App` is a tiny Meteor app. The `API` is a much larger app also using Node.js. The `App` needs to request a file from `API` (which is served happily) and proxy the stream back to the client.

How can I stream the resposne from `API` *through* `App` to the client?

Here's the route squeleton on the Meteor app I have so far :

```
import connectRoute from 'connect-route';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
    
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(connectRoute(router => {

   router.get('/pdf/:hash', async (req, res, next) => {
      const { hash } = req.params;

      // debug
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(`Requested file hash: ${hash}`);

      // TODO : proxy response headers back to client
      // const response = await fetch(`http://api.domain.local/files/${hash}`);
   });

}));
```

I don't know what to do with the `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution :

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(connectRoute(router => {

   router.get('/pdf/:hash', async (req, res, next) => {
      const { hash } = req.params;

      try {
         const response = await fetch(`${API_ROOT}/files/${hash}/`);

         res.setHeader('content-disposition', response.headers.get('content-disposition') );
         res.setHeader('content-type', response.headers.get('content-type'));
         response.body.pipe(res);
      } catch (e) {
         res.writeHead(500);
      }
   });

}));
```

It is not complete as it does not handle various HTTP errors (e.g. `400`, `404`), but it works.